# Not getting preview screen in activity_main.xml in android studio(version 2.2)on. There is only + sign with 2 slashes.?

Tags: android

As shown image besides palette window I am not getting screen of virtual device. I am only getting + sign with 2slashes.

[image: 1]

Comment: Image shows gradle sync exception. Is your gradle file configured properly?

Comment: How to configured it??

Comment: Please upload both of your gradle files

Comment: Please upload `build.gradle(Project:project name)` and `build.gradle(Module:app)` by editing your question and properly structuring it

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the Android API from the dropdown. Please see the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: Assign your sdk path to Android Studio and then try again.